# Fixed div, bottom and top set, but want dynamic height

Tags: html, css

I want a div to be `position: fixed;` with a `top: 125px; bottom: 125px;`

The content of this div is dynamic, so the sum height of the children of this popup is not always taking up the entire div's height, meaning the parent is showing at the bottom of the children. What would be the way around this? Would I have to use margin instead of top and bottom?

Comment: That depends on what you want to see instead of the parent div at that position. The `body`? Some other element?

Comment: The question isn't clear. Can you post a fiddle with your current code?

Comment: Setting `top` and `bottom` of a non-replaced absolutely positioned element specifies the height of the element if the `height` property isn't specified explicitly. So, you'd probably need to omit `bottom`: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#abs-non-replaced-height

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your complete layout, but maybe probably just omitting the `bottom` css would be enough.

If you don't specify a size restriction a div should, by default, dynamically grow and shrink to fit the contents of it's children.  In this case you are forcing it to a certain size by setting an absolute position for both top and bottom, thereby creating a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `bottom` here, just set the `top` and let the height expand naturally to fit the children. If you don't want the parent to ever be less than a specific height then use `min-height` to set that.